# How can I override a java method, and change the nullability of a parameter?

Tags: java, android, nullable, kotlin

I'm overriding a method from a Java library, and the parameter for the function is annotated as `@NonNull`. However, when the method is called, the parameter frequently comes in with a `null` value. When I override the method in Kotlin, it forces me to respect the `@NonNull` annotation and mark the parameter as not nullable. Of course, Kotlin throws an exception at run time when the parameter comes in with a null value. Is there some way I can override the method in Kotlin and ignore the `@NonNull` annotation?

Specifically, I'm using the appcompat library for Android. The method is in AppCompatActivity.java

```
@CallSuper
public void onSupportActionModeFinished(@NonNull ActionMode mode) {
}
```

The override in Kotlin:

```
override fun onSupportActionModeFinished(mode: ActionMode) {
    super.onSupportActionModeFinished(mode)
}
```

Comment: The reason it is vital that you follow the NonNull pattern is because it also comes with the CallSuper annotation. If you passed a null value, there would be no checks in the super method since the annotation is to ensure the value isn't null. You will almost certainly end up with a NPE. If you aren't calling this method explicitly outside of the framework it should never come with a null value as the framework will respect this annotation.

Comment: The library is calling that method and passing a null value, not my code. The library is breaking it's own annotation. When I override in Java and allow the null to go through to the super method, no NPE occurs.

Comment: What in the world, yea that's just odd.

Comment: I asked about this in Slack and there are no current plans to address the issue. https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/general/p1459529683002816

Answer (score 10):

There seems to be no straightforward way to suppress nullability annotation handling by Kotlin compiler.

As a workaround, you can make an intermediate derived class with `@Nullable` annotation in Java: when Kotlin compiler sees both `@Nullable` and `@NonNull` on the same code element it behaves as if there were no nullability annotations. Then just subclass it in Kotlin. Example:

Consider a class with a `@NonNull` parameter in Java:

```
abstract class Base {
    public abstract void f(@NonNull String str);
    //...
}
```

Kotlin understands the annotation: `f(str: String)`, the type is non-null.

Now extend `Base` in Java, override the method and add `@Nullable` annotation to the parameter in `Intermediate`:

```
abstract class Intermediate extends Base {
    @Override
    public abstract void f(@Nullable String str);
}
```

For `Intermediate`, Kotlin sees `f(str: String!)`, the parameter has [platform type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types), that is, its nullability is unknown.

After that, you will be able to declare nullable parameter in a Kotlin subclass of `Intermediate`:

```
class Derived(): Intermediate() {
    override fun f(url: String?) { ... }
}
```

Comment: I just hope they add a way to suppress or ignore that warning for cases like this. It's a pain to create that intermediate class just to fix one parameter.